# WNS Notification : Channel URL incompatible with caller app

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, wns

I'm currently developping an mobile application based on Cordova (version 4.0.0) for Windows Phone 8.1.

I implemented the Java code from API Java-WNS (from github of fernandospr) to send notification to my device.

When I push the notification message to WNS, I get this error :

```
Client in-bound response
403
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-WNS-DEBUG-TRACE: DB5SCH101111133
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 10:44:55 GMT
Content-Length: 0
X-WNS-STATUS: dropped
X-WNS-ERROR-DESCRIPTION: Channel URL incompatible with caller app
X-WNS-MSG-ID: 6D850FC61AE7FDB5
X-WNS-NOTIFICATIONSTATUS: dropped
```

Here's the different steps to configure my app to receive notifications :

- I registered my app from windows developper dashboard
- I have a SID package : ms-app://s-1-15-2-[...]-[...]-[...]-[...]-[...]-[...]-[...]-2403721117
- I have also my client secret like this (just an example) : Nk2C+pmadqcHNQR51lN6F7LGaJYUTRPb
- This is my channel URI obtained from WNS :

  ```
  https://db5.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAAD8sfbDrL9h7mN%2bmwlkSkQZCIfv4QKeu1hYRipj2zNvXaMi9ZAax%2f6CDfysyHp61STCO1pCFPt%2b9L4Jod72JhIcjDr8b2GxuUOBMTP%2b6%2bqxEfSB9iZfSATdZbdF7cJHSRA%3d
  ```
- **Most important, I associated my app to windows store from Visual Studio**. Then, package name, publisher display and publisher ID have been added to my appxmanifest.file

Here's the appxmanifest.file (truely name "package.phone.appxmanifest from platforms/windows folder and cordova windows phone project) :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest" xmlns:m3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/manifest" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest">
    <Identity Name="company-name.70**********2" Publisher="CN=02******-****-****-****-***********9" Version="1.1.0.0" />
    <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="06******-****-****-****-**********k" PhonePublisherId="s*******-****-****-****-***********5" />
    <Properties>
        <DisplayName>Demo Windows App Phone</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>My Company Name</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Logo>images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
    </Properties>
    <Prerequisites>
        <OSMinVersion>6.3.1</OSMinVersion>
        <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
    </Prerequisites>
    <Resources>
        <Resource Language="x-generate" />
    </Resources>
    <Applications>
        <Application Id="com.company-name.demo" StartPage="www/index.html">
            <m3:VisualElements BackgroundColor="transparent" Description="CordovaApp" DisplayName="Demo Windows App Phone" ForegroundText="light" Square150x150Logo="images\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="images\Square44x44Logo.png">
                <m3:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="images\Square71x71Logo.png" Wide310x150Logo="images\Wide310x150Logo.png">
                    <m3:ShowNameOnTiles>
                        <m3:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
                        <m3:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
                    </m3:ShowNameOnTiles>
                </m3:DefaultTile>
                <m3:SplashScreen Image="images\SplashScreenPhone.png" />
            </m3:VisualElements>
            <ApplicationContentUriRules>
                <Rule Match="https://dev.company-name.fr/demo-windows-app/*" Type="include" />
            </ApplicationContentUriRules>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
    <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
        <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
        <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
    </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

From server side, I use the authentification to WNS with two parameters :

- SID package
- Client secret password

**I checked differents topics about this error and the most of the useful answer is to associate the app to windows store. But I always did it and I don't work for me.**

If I understand well, WNS platform just need to know the ID App (SID package) to find my app and to send notification to my app. I don't need to deploy my app through the windows store.

Do you have an idea about how to fix it ? Do you think I forget something or do a mistake ?

EDIT :

**I'm thinking I find the problem ! I'm working on it and when I'll resolve my problem, I'll come back here to post my solution.**

Comment: Let us know how it goes :-). I checked that channel URI, and it is indeed for a different SID than yours: s-1-15-2-1503184759-1914855698-947131399-753488827-3851864701-3079576880-3517626277. As you mentioned, most likely it's some issue with associating the app with the Windows Store - otherwise behind-the-scenes VS will deploy it with a different app because it can't sign it using your publisher identity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution about my problem. I'm stupid because I didn't see the relationship between the association of my app to windows store and the appx archive which must have generated. I deployed the wrong appx and that's why I never received the notifications windows. In fact, the wrong appx was never associated to the windows store...

So, here's the steps (from Visual Studio 2015 RC) to deploy the appx archive linked to windows store :

- Go to project tab and select windows store
- Click on *create app packages*
- Following the differents steps to generate an appx archive with the windows store informations associated (one of steps will be associate your app with the windows store)
- the appx archive generated is stored to the following folder (in my case) : C:\Users\pcharpin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\demo-app-windows\demo-app-windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Phone_1.1.0.0_arm_Test
- To deploy this archive on your remote device, use the *Windows Phone Application Deployment 8.1* tool. Select target as remote device and select also the app package which is *CordovaApp.Phone_1.1.0.0_arm_Test*. To finish, click on deploy and your app will be deploy on your remote device.
- You're ready to send notifications windows and receive them to your windows phone device

**So, don't forget to create an app package to associate it to the windows store and can receive the notifications windows.**

You can retrieve the guidelines about this from documentation of *Create a Windows 8.1 app* package (excepted about the deployment's step).

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting this error:  `X-WNS-ERROR-DESCRIPTION: Invalid channel URL`; any ideas why? Should I escape somehow the registration URL I retrieved from the app registration event? I'm using PHP and curl().

Answer (score 4):

If the notification is still not working after associating the application, double check the below configuration as well.

1. Goto Windows Dev Center of your account -> Dashboard
2. Select you app -> Services -> Push notifications
3. Click on "Live Services site" link
4. Below "Package SID" there is config for "Application Identity" like,

   < Identity Name="**09FSERVSD.YourAppName**" Publisher="CN=xxxxxx"/>
5. Open your application appxmanifest in the text editor and make sure the same name is added in the Identify tag.

Associating the app through the VS tool ideally should update this entry with "Name" and "Publisher". But in my case it updated only "Publisher" and I had to manually set this value to make it work. This way WNS will know that the target application is same as the one which is associated and the notification should go through.

Hope this helps for those who is struggling with error "Channel URL incompatible with caller app" while testing WNS.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all of you guys,

In my case it was the `Publisher` field (in `package.windows10.appxmanifest`, `package.windows.appxmanifest` and `package.phone.appxmanifest`) that defaulted to `CN=$username$`.

```
<Identity Name="com.CordovaApp" Publisher="CN=$username$" Version="2.2.11.0" />
```

Once set as such, everything went smooth:

```
<Identity Name="COM.CordovaApp" Publisher="CN=11111111-2222-3333-444444444444" Version="2.2.11.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you continue receiving the error message "X-WNS-ERROR-DESCRIPTION: Channel URL incompatible with caller app" after you've setup the  correctly, try to delete the *_TemporaryKey.pfx file from the project directory.